# Manually install modules in Adobe CQ 5.6

Tags: javascript, java, maven, adobe, aem

I try to install Custom Google Search module [from here](https://github.com/infielddesign/aem-id-googlesearch). The [documentation](http://www.infielddesign.com/technology/adobe-experience-manager/google-custom-search/documentation/) explains how to install it using `package manager`, but this way I'll have to install the same package on every CQ instance. Is there a way to include the package inside the code I deploy to CQ, so it will be saved in the repository and everyone that will pull my code will have this module already installed?

Answer (score 1):

An organization specific Nexus or Apache Archiva can be helpful in this situation for maintaining/deploying packages which are **not** in Central Maven/Adobe repo.

If your package is not in any central repo ("Custom Google Search module" in your case) , you can upload[0] the package to your local/organization specific Nexus/Apache Archiva and tell your/team member's POM file to download from that .

So, your pom.xml needs to have the repository URL of local/organization specific Nexus/Apache Archiva or your maven settings should have a mirror pointing to your org. Nexus/Archiva.

Your project can have a dependency of Custom Google Search Module as follows ,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>infield-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>googlesearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>content-package</type>
</dependency>
```

To embed and deploy this GSA package along with your code , you can leverage Content package maven plugin [1].

*The whole setup/procedure might not be as complicated as it sounds from my answer !*

[0]https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html
[1]https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html

Answer (score 1):

If you mean including that `aem-id-googlesearch` content package inside another content package that you are building yourself, CQ does indeed support nested content packages.

If you're building your own content package using the `content-package-maven-plugin` you can use its `subPackage` configuration to define the embedded package, as explained in the [plugin documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html).